# Debugging problems in Visual Studio 2005 - No source code available for the current location

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005

I've searched up and down Google for others with a similar problem, and while I can find the error I don't think that other people have the same base problem that I do.

Basically, I had to create a project for a unit-testing environment in order to run this test suite.

First, I add my original C file, compile, and then a test file (C++) is generated.  I then exclude my original source from the project, include this test script (which includes the original source at the top), and then run.

I can debug the test file fine, but when it jumps to the original C file I get the dreaded 'no source code available for the current location' error.

Both files are located within the same location, and I compiled the original file without any issue.

Anybody have any thoughts about this?  Its driving me crazy!

Comment: Wait a minute...just to get this straight: You compiled a C-File, created a C++-File with this C code in it and removed the original C-File?

Comment: Yep, that's how the test suite is setup in all its glory.
The original C file is not to be compiled in the project, yet still included within the C++ file.

Comment: espais, this question is better suited to http://stackoverflow.com/.  please don't crosspost; it will be migrated automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the test suite was deleting the intermediate debug code generated by Vis Studio.  I had to add some flags into it in order to keep these files.